# .htaccess and the word "find"

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess that does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^find /findgames.php [L]
RewriteRule ^find/ /findgames.php [L]
```

If i remove the letter 'd' in 'find' everything works great:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^fin /findgames.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fin/ /findgames.php [L]
```

What am i missing? Is find a keyword? The second I have the letters 'find' in a row, i get a 'Internal Server Error' on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is absolutely correct and expected behaviour (the 'Internal Server Error' message) in your case. Although you should see the same error even without letter `d`.

The reason -- bad matching pattern -- it is way to broad. What `^find` means? It means -- match URL that starts with `find` (leading slash is stripped by Apache). This will match `/find`, `/find/`, `/findme` etc -- as well as your target -- `/findgames.php`.

Most likely (in this particular case) you have **infinite rewrite loop** which Apache has to break at some point, hence the error. You can check Apache's error log for **exact** error message -- it will explain it quite well.

In any case -- this *should* work for you -- it will redirect requests for `/find` as well as `/find/` (exact matches) to `/findgames.php`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^find/?$ /findgames.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a ton! Appreciate the full explanation.