# .htaccess Rewrite issue. Possibly reserved words?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

This does not require much explanation, quite simply, how does the following work:

```
RewriteRule ^errors/browser/?$ /_errors/browser.php?error=browser [NC,QSA,L]
```

and this does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^error/browser/?$ /_errors/browser.php?error=browser [NC,QSA,L]
```

**The only difference in two above snippets, is the removal of the letter `s` from the end of the word `error`**

I cannot understand why the addition of an `s` on the word `error` suddenly makes this code work. The only explanation I can think of is that `error` is a reserved word? Is this the case?

If this is the case then how can I match and rewrite the word `error` using an `.htaccess` file?

**UPDATE**

This is my whole `.htaccess` file:

```
# Define the default document
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Compress all HTML, Javascript, CSS, XML... files
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Set the error page rewrites
RewriteRule ^errors/browser/?$ /_errors/browser.php?error=browser [NC,QSA,L]

# Set the general first level rewrites
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/?$ $1.php? [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\/([a-z-0-9]+)\/?$ $1.php?id=$2&amp; [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Check whether your HSP has mod_security or Suhosin.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I don't have either enabled :-)

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file?

Comment: @w3d Yes, will post the whole file, hold on a sec :-)

Comment: Some distributions create `Alias`es for error documents... you seem to be affected by this. Look for `ErrorDocument` or `Alias` lines in your global/`VirtualHost` apache configuration (one of `apache.conf`, `httpd.conf`, `conf.d/*.conf`, `sites-enabled/*` etc.)

Comment: Aside... you include `&amp;` in your last `RewriteRule` - this is an **HTML** entity, so I wouldn't have thought it should be used here.

Comment: @w3d you're right. Even if it's not related to the problem it's definitely not right and does something different than is expected (creates new `GET` variable `amp`... but I'm not sure how will it deal with the semicolon)

Comment: @KamilŠrot the `&amp;` was there for appending the query string but you are right, it is not necessary. That particular bit of code was copied from one of my older sites so it is slightly outdated and possibly (in this case it is) incorrect.

Comment: @BenCarey the `&` doesn't append query string... it's the `QSA` flag doing it... anyway the point is, you should use plain `&` if you want to construct query string in `mod_rewrite`... `&amp;` is HTML entity (as @w3d mentioned) and is interpreted differently than you expect (see my previous comment)

Comment: @KamilŠrot I am aware of this, as I mentioned, this code was taken from an old website and was mainly for example purposes, excluding the particular rewrite I was referring to, the other parts were not tested. The `QSA` flag appends the query string, but what if there is a query string already on the rewrite, so you are effectively appending the query string with a query string. Surely you will need an `&` to split the two query strings!? This is why it was there in the first place

Comment: Is there a file named `error.php` or `error.html`? Or a folder named `error`

Comment: @Gerben There is a folder called `_errors`, and within this folder is a file called `error.php`

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` to the htaccess!

Comment: @Gerben Tried that, didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite strange that vim will highlight the word "error", but you may simply try this to hack it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^erro[r]/index.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

And here is an issue maybe related: [question-10872503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872503/htaccess-and-the-word-find)